# How to reach element with ng-select change event

Tags: angular, dom, select

Is it possible to get $event as same as with input (change) event in ng-select? On input (change) event, $event is fired as event with native element where i can reach element in DOM. With ng-select, (change) event is fired with selected model as $event.

I need to reach element in DOM when item is changed in ng-select. Is it possible ?

```
<input (change)="myFunc($event)"></input>
<ng-select (change)="myFunc($event)"></ng-select>

myFunc(event){
// input is full $event
// ng-select is only selected model
}
```

Comment: pass input reference along with event,
<input #inref (change)="myFunc($event, inref)">.
like this way, you can get a 'HTMLInputElement' in your component.

Comment: @KarthikKrishnaBaiju this works perfectly, thank you